# How to return a function from React Hooks that need access to the state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm building a custom hook to manage the data coming from a fetch/axios/promise/whateveryouwant function, this hooks allow me to update the data whenever I want using an update function that I return at the end of my hook.

So for now I have two states inside my hooks:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<T>(defaultValue); // the data coming from the fetch, T is defined by the user of the hook
const [query, setQuery] = useState<Array<{ key: string; value: string }>>([]); // array of query option for the URL
```

I wanted to implement a dynamic way to add query string to the URL, so I used the query state to have an array of object representing what I wanted but I cannot access the value of the query inside of the update function when calling from outside. Here is the hooks, I highlited the important part :

```
export default function useFetchV2<T>(
  defaultValue: T,
  getData: (queryString?: string) => Promise<T>
): {
  update: () => void;
  data: T;
  updateQueryValue: (key: string, value: string) => void; // update, data, updateQueryValue are the return value of the hook.
} {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>(defaultValue);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<Array<{ key: string; value: string }>>([]); // THE STATE I WANT TO ACCESS

  console.log(query, data); // Here the state is updating well and everything seems fine

  const update = useCallback((): void => {
    let queryString;

    console.log(query, data);

   // But here is the problem, query and data are both at their default value. The state inside the hooks is correct but not here.

    if (query.length > 0) { // query.length always at 0
      queryString = _.reduce(
        query,
        (acc, el) => {
          return `${acc}${el.key}=${el.value.toString()}`;
        },
        '?'
      );
      console.log(queryString);
    }
    getData(queryString).then(res => setData(res));
  }, [data, getData, query]);

  const updateQueryValue = useCallback(
    (key: string, value: string): void => {
      const index = query.findIndex(el => el.key === key);
      if (index !== -1) {
        if (!value) {
          const toto = [...query];
          _.pullAt(toto, index);
          setQuery(toto);
        } else {
          setQuery(prev =>
            prev.map(el => {
              if (el.key === key) {
                return { key, value };
              }
              return el;
            })
          );
        }
      } else {
        console.log(key, value); // everything is logging well here, good key and value
        setQuery([...query, { key, value }]); // setQuery correctly update the state
      }
      update();
    },
    [query, update]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    update();
  }, []);

  return { update, data, updateQueryValue };
}
```

It might be the way I'm exporting the function, I'm still not used to the scope.

I called updateQueryValue from a component. The function is called, state is changed, but the update function can't see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is calling `setQuery` and then immediately calling `update` and expecting `query` to be updated value, but it will always be the *current* value of `query`. Getting that to happen is the use case of `useEffect`.

```
  } else {
    console.log(key, value); // everything is logging well here, good key and value
    setQuery([...query, { key, value }]); // setQuery correctly update the state
  }
  
  // This will *always* see the current value of `query`, not the one that
  // was just created in the `else` block above.
  update();
```

1. It sounds like the code should run `update` after `query` is updated, which is exactly what `useEffect` is for.

```js
const updateQueryValue = useCallback(
    (key: string, value: string): void => {
      const index = query.findIndex(el => el.key === key);
      if (index !== -1) {
        if (!value) {
          const toto = [...query];
          _.pullAt(toto, index);
          setQuery(toto);
        } else {
          setQuery(prev =>
            prev.map(el => {
              if (el.key === key) {
                return { key, value };
              }
              return el;
            })
          );
        }
      } else {
        setQuery([...query, { key, value }]); // setQuery correctly update the state
      }

      // This call isn't needed, it will always "see" the old value of
      // `query`
      // update();
    },
    [query, update]
  );

  // Call `update` once when this custom hook is first called as well as
  // whenever `query` changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    update();
  }, [query]); // <-- this is new, add `query` as a dependency
```

2. `useCallback` is only needed if something is relying on the identity of the function to make decisions; e.g. if a component receives the function as a prop, it checks whether the prop changes to decide whether to re-render. `update` in this case does not need a `useCallback` and might make this hook slightly harder to debug.

```js
function update() {
    let queryString;
    if (query.length > 0) { // query.length always at 0
      queryString = _.reduce(
        query,
        (acc, el) => {
          return `${acc}${el.key}=${el.value.toString()}`;
        },
        '?'
      );
      console.log(queryString);
    }
    getData(queryString).then(res => setData(res));
  });
```

Comment: Ok it did the tricks! Thank you for the explanation on the useCallback I always struggle to really know when to use it. I just had to JSON.stringify the query in the dependency array to make it work as expected (to avoid infinite update)